# Cannot run project - the selection cannot be launched and there are no recent lanuches

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

i have following problem:

Yesterday i worked on my selenium&maven project in java on eclipse and after work i export project as archive, today i want to import whole project and run it on second computer, but i receive 'the selection cannot be launched and there are no recent lanuches'.
I tried run configuration, but there's no effect.
My archive is available here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BB0tqege1iWE_qdbHSEhfvNuFqPa8SO7 or https://github.com/mtpx/af/tree/master/automationFramework

How can I execute this project?
It using Selenium, Maven and TestNG, so there's no main class here

Comment: Try enabling maven nature. If it does not work, try zipping the root of the source code from first computer, transferring to second, ensuring JDK and Maven exist on 2nd, and importing maven project using eclipse.

Comment: Source on google drive was zipped on first computer. I tried import as existing maven project, and it doesnt work. Also in Run Configuration i can choose main class, but in TestNG project there's no main fuction, i have only page objects and test scenarios classes

Comment: Ok, now its working, after adding external library in project properties for selenium and testNG :)

Comment: Good to hear that.. Can you also post this in the answer and mark it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the project you have in hands was not exported properly, missing important metadata for the compiler.

Make sure the project is being correctly exported using (right click) export option and not only copy+paste/zip+share.